# How do you proove that a torus is an orientable 2-dim manifold?

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let the torus $M := \{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 | (\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-R)^2+z^2=r^2 \}$ with $r<R$

Afaik, you can prove that a manifold is orientable by calculating if the derivative of the determinant of the two compsited mappings are positive, i.e. $\det(\Psi_2^{-1}\circ\Psi_1)^\prime > 0$. But if I'm not given any mapping functions, how would I go about it?

The paremeterized equations should be:
$$x=(R + r\cos v)\cos u$$
$$y=(R + r\cos v)\sin u$$
$$z=r\sin v$$

Do I use the parametric equations to calculate these mappings, or is there a better way to do this?

And about the two dimensionality: what is required here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your torus is already embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which you can orient canonically (choose as positive the basis $e_1,e_2,e_3$).
$\mathbb{R}^3$ has also a metric given by the standard scalar product.
This metric induces a volume form namely $\nu = dx^1\wedge dx^2 \wedge dx^3$.
If you can find a normal unit vector along the torus $N$, then the contracted form $\iota_N \nu $ will be a volume form for the torus (so it will be orientable).

I recall that by definition $\iota_N \nu (X_1,X_2) = \nu(N, X_1,X_2)$ so $\forall X_1,X_2 \in T_p M $ linearly independent tangent vectors  you have that $ \iota_N \nu (X_1,X_2)>0$ (definition of volume form).

So the point is to find a vector field $N:M\to \mathbb{R}^3 $ such that $N$ is orthogonal to the tangent space of the torus and also of unit length.

Can you complete the answer by yourself? Here is the solution

> $$N(u,v) = \frac {\psi_u(u,v)\times \psi_v(u,v)}{||\psi_u(u,v)\times \psi_v(u,v)||}  $$ where $\psi(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))$ is the local parametrization

By the way, another method to prove that the torus is orientable is that since it is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1\times \mathbb{S}^1$ and the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ is orientable then also the torus it is.

Comment: Thanks, that made it clearer! A couple of questions though; what does $X_1,X_2$ represent in this context? And also for $N(u,v)$, shouldn't that be the $\partial\Psi_u$ instead of $\Psi_u$ etc?

Comment: $X_1,X_2$ are two vectors tangent to the torus at a certain point $p$, that are also linearly independent, (so since the normal is orthogonal to them the triple $N,X_1,X_2$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$). when I write $\psi_u$ I mean $\frac {\partial\psi}{\partial u}$.

Comment: Great! Ok, so they would be gradient and curl then, for every point p on the surface?

Comment: you mean for the formula for $N$? Think of it like this: when taking the partial derivatives of the parametrization, you obtain a tangent vector $\psi_u$. Since the parametrization is a submersion then $\psi_u$ and $\psi_v$ are linearly independent at any point (they generate the whole tangent space). So if you compute the cross product you get a third vector that will be orthogonal to the two and so normal to the surface.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!